# Generic Method Type Parameter

Tags: java, generics

I've this method that takes 3 parameters of type T that implements interface Comparable

```
public static < T extends Comparable< T > > T maximum( T x, T y, T z ) {}
```

I am asking about declaring this in other way, like the following (assuming that it takes any Comparable object as its parameters)

```
public static <Comparable <T>> T maximum (T x, T y, T z){}
```

another question, in the first declaration, I know that Comparable is an interface so why it's written as `<T extends Comparable<T>>` instead of `<T implements Comparable<T>>`??

Comment: in generics you have to use word `extends` for both Class type and Interface type.

Comment: for best results use `T extends Comparable<? super T>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your questions can be answered with: this is the Java syntax. In the Java language a parameterized method is declared like this:

```
[optional modifiers] <T> [return type] foo() {}
```

It *declares* a *type parameter* named `T`, which can be constrained with an *upper bound* with the syntax:

```
T extends [type expression]
```

In the rest of the method (return type, formal parameters list, method body) `T` refers to the type you pass when invoke the method. In a declaration like:

```
Comparable<T>
```

`T` is not a type parameter, but it's a **type argument** used to instantiate the parameterized type `Comparable<E>`, and belongs to a bigger scope like, say:

```
class Foo<T> {
  public Comparable<T> foo(T arg1, T arg2) {}
}
```

Note that the text `<Comparable<T>>` (a type enclosed in angle brackets) in a source file isn't allowed at all. It doesn't mean anything to a compiler, which will refuse to compile the file.

Similarly, regarding your second question, `extends` is simply a keyword in the Java language and has two different meanings:

1. It can be used in a class declaration to inherit another class
2. It can be used to put an upper bound on a type parameter

The Java creators could have decided to use a different keyword to distinguish the two cases, but they simply *overloaded* an existing one because they felt it was easier to remember for developers. But they are definitely *different keywords*, that's why you don't use *implements* when declaring an upper bound for a type parameter.

Answer (score 4):

`public static <Comparable <T>> T maximum (T x, T y, T z){}` is not compiling because the parameter T is undeclared for the method.

> I know that Comparable is an interface so why it's written as > instead of >??

The syntax for bounded [type parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5) is with `extends` not `implements` even if the parameter is required to implement an interface.

Comment: Even if `T` were declared as a type parameter for the enclosing type, that code wouldn't compile, because a string like `<Comparable<T>>` is simply not allowed in the Java language. It doesn't mean anything

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Javadoc for `Collections.sort`. The signature is:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

This is so if I have

```
class A implements Comparable<A> {...}
class B extends A {...}
// ...
List<B> bs = ...
Collections.sort(bs);
```

I can sort the List because B is comparable through class A's comparator. So, write:

```
public static < T extends Comparable< ? super T > > T maximum( T x, T y, T z ) {}
```